# Referencing own Class using "this."

Tags: java, this

Simple question that I couldn't find an answer to online, I created a GUI class that extends JFrame and in the constructor I create the Frame using "setSize(10,10);" and so on, however, many online examples use "this.setSize(10,10);" so my question is; is there any difference at all in the following:

```
setSize(10,10);
this.setSize(10,10);
```

Comment: no difference, but IMO the second line is more maintainable/readable than the first line.

Comment: Note that referring to a variable is a different story - if there is a local variable `foo` and instance variable `foo`, then `foo` will refer to the local variable while `this.foo` will refer to the instance variable. If there is no local variable, `foo` will refer to the instance variable.

Answer (score 2):

If you don't use `this` keyword before members of the class, it will be added automatically while compiling. So, referring to any member of the class from some function (like constructor) can be done without `this` keyword if the function you are at doesn't have the argument with the same name as the member. But if it does then you would have to use `this` to refer to the class member variable instead of parameter.

Comment: what if it wasn't in the constructor of the class?

Comment: @Aominè Same, it could be in any function of the class, `this` is automatically added while compiling, as aman5319 said.

Comment: Well, your answer suggests that it's only the same if `this` is used in the constructor. can you update your answer to remove this ambiguity please ;-)

Answer (score 0):

No there is no difference 
when you call your method like this

```
setSize(10,10);
```

during compilation java compiler automatically converts it into

```
this.setSize(10,10);
```